# DynamoDBMappingException when using Java Generics

Tags: java, generics, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table called 'inbox'. In it will be stored messages that are sent to and from users. There will be more than one type of message, and based on the type, data may come along with the message. I have an object UserMessage that maps to the inbox table. While there will be common fields (e.g. sendTo, sentFrom) for all messages, the data will vary in its structure.

Rather than using a Map for this data, the thought occurs that using Java Generics might be a better approach. I have an object annotated with @DynamoDBDocument, and DynamoDBMapper will serialize that to JSON. When the member variable is declared as:

```
private ContactData data;
```

indeed, the result is expected. data is serialized to JSON and stored in the data attribute in inbox in the format of ContactData's annotations. However, to get the flexibility desired by using generic types, a call to DynamoDBMapper.save() throws DynamoDBMappingException: Cannot convert T to a class.

Here is the UserMessage class:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="inbox")
public class UserMessage<T> {

    private String toId;
    private T data;

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="data")
public T getData() {
    return data;
}
public void setData(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}
@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="toId")
public String getToId() {
     return toId;
}
public void setToId(String to) {
    this.toId = to;
   }
}
```

And the code for ContactData:

```
@DynamoDBDocument
public class ContactData {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;

 @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "firstname")
public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}
public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}
 @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "lastname")
public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}
public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
 @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "email")
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
}
```

The controller code to set this up is:

```
UserMessage<ContactData> message = new UserMessage<ContactData>();
ContactData cd = new ContactData();
cd.setEmail("jane@test.com");
cd.setFirstname("Jane");
cd.setLastname("Smith");

message.setToId("test@email.com");
message.setData(cd)
DynamoDB.getMapper().save(message);
```

I'm fairly inexperienced, and generic types are brand new to me, so I hope I am using them correctly. I think I am. I just think that DynamoDBMapper can't map to the right class in this case.
Thanks
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you use a non-standard attribute class you need to provider a marshaller. Here I used a global Object marshaller you can probably use to just *JSON-ify* anything you'd like.

I personally prefer using static types, each one with a defined marshaller I can reason about, but ymmv.

```
public class GenericDBEntity<T>
{
    ..
    private T extra;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    @DynamoDBMarshalling(marshallerClass=ObjectMarshaller.class)
    public T getExtra()
    {
        return extra;
    }
    public void setExtra(T extra)
    {
        this.extra = extra;
    }

    public static class ObjectMarshaller implements DynamoDBMarshaller<Object>
    {
        @Override
        public String marshall(Object getterReturnResult)
        {
            return getterReturnResult.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public Object unmarshall(Class<Object> clazz, String obj)
        {
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```